# LLVM "source" package manager?

Tags: linux, package-management, source

To my understanding, the main advantage of a binary package manager is install speed, while the main advantage to a source package manager is cross-arch compatibility, so why not something in-between?

If packages were compiled down to LLVM and distributed from there, a package manager would be able to distribute it to multiple architectures, and possibly even completely different operating systems without needing tons of copies of the same software per architecture and OS while also not needing the ridiculous compile time of high-level languages. Is this viable, does something like it already exist, or is it kind of a useless idea?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does something like that in the App store:

> Bitcode
>
> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
> you upload to App Store Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled
> and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to
> re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a
> new version of your app to the App Store.

(https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f)

Comment: Oh that's really interesting, although I wonder if any actually distribute in that form. It looks like Apple is using it to keep their own compile time down, but still distributed as binary.